# C# Entity Framework filtering with .Where()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, filtering

I am working in C# using Entity Framework and I am trying to filter a query of contacts to get all contact that have the same Id. I can get all `Contacts`, but I'm having issues filtering using `Where`. I know somethings wrong but I can't quite pinpoint it, any help would be appreciated.

See relevant code below:

```
public IEnumerable<model.Contact> Execute(GetContactById parameters)
{
    IEnumerable<model.Contact> ContactsById = null;

    DbRetryHandler.RetryHandler(delegate(DeviceModelContext retryContext)
    {
        ContactsById = retryContext.Contact
                    .Where(c => c.Id.equals(parameters.Id))
                    .Select(c => new model.Contact
                     {
                         // unrelated code
                     });
                });

                return ContactsById;
}
```

Comment: What is `parameters.Id` data type?

Comment: Are you getting an exception? did you try to use `==` instead of `Equals`?

Comment: @YacoubMassad yes I've tried that, result remains Null. I can see when I run this with a break point that c.Id never gets a value so ultimately it just compares parameters.Id to Null.

Comment: @Ian parameters.Id is a Guid.

Comment: Have you tried intercepting the sql query with the profiler?

Comment: did you try `retryContext.Contact.ToList()` and see if you are getting any values?

Comment: Since Guid is a [struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can use the == operator, as suggested by @YacoubMassad

Comment: What type is `Contact.Id`? Is it nullable type? You mention `c.Id` being null. If it is a `Guid` then that is not possible as it is a struct

Comment: @ManojAnavatti I know that it works, I have run it without the .Where() and I can get a complete list of Contacts. The moment I add the Where() I get a null return for a search I know should return 2 values.

Comment: @Nkosi all .Id values are Guid. c.Id is not null, The query returns null, as in it claims there are no matches. But I can see when I use break point that c.Id is never assigned a Guid which I don't see why.

Comment: Then @FrederikPetersen please see what query is executed through profiler.

Comment: Please check the table configuration for column Id. Sometimes GUID columns are ignored and GUID is generated for runtime logic only.

Comment: @FrederikPetersen that is very strange if c.Id is never assigned any value. How does your model look like? Also, how does your data table look like?

Comment: is camerasByDeviceId IQueryable? Where do you actually execute the query (likely with .FirstOrDefault())? Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the purpose of `camerasByDeviceId`? Why are you filling it with data, only to return `ContactsById` which is always null?

Comment: @FrederikPetersen you SHOULD NOT alter the original question and update it with the working solution because other programmers running in the same problem can not follow up what was wrong originally. that's what the answers are for. Please put it back to original state (code that isn't running)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The provider has issues recognizing expressions it cannot translate to SQL. Try to simplify the expressions so that it can be translated to SQL more easily.

```
public IEnumerable<model.Contact> Execute(GetContactById parameters)
{
     IEnumerable<model.Contact> ContactsById = null;
     DbRetryHandler.RetryHandler(delegate(DeviceModelContext retryContext)
     {
         var parametersId = parameters.Id; // <-- store id in variable
         camerasByDeviceId = retryContext.Contact
           .Where(c => c.Id == parametersId) // <-- use == instead of Equals
           .Select(c => new model.Camera
           {
               // unrelated code
           });
     });

     return ContactsById;
}
```